Google Chrome won't launch properly under Ubuntu 24.04
I have a new-ish machine (< 2 weeks old) on which is installed Ubuntu 24.04.1.  Google Chrome was not installed by default, I installed it.  It had worked for as long as I've had it.  I then rebooted the machine and, voila, Chrome no longer works.  That is to say, it starts processes that I can view with ps -ef | grep chrome and if I right-click on the dash icon for it, it shows an open window, but if I click on that window, it doesn't open.
I have no clue why this is happening.  I've tried searching but nothing matches the scenario mentioned above. I can't find anything relating to Chrome in dmesg.  What other logs might I search?
I am used to Chrome and it is a pain for me to be doing this through Firefox. How may I fix this?
Update: Apparently I have both google-chrome and google-chrome-stable installed. I have no idea which one the dash icon launches but both fail with similar messages when launched from terminal:
$ google-chrome
MESA-INTEL: warning: cannot initialize blitter engine
[53354:53354:1230/084355.394959:ERROR:content_settings_pref.cc(381)] Invalid pattern strings: http://[*.]xn--%20its%20a%20reflection%20of%20the%20commitment%20and%20heart%20that%20everyone%20brings%20to%20the%20arava%20institute,%20no%20matter%20how%20challenging%20it%20becomes-ut63i.%20,*
[53354:53354:1230/084355.571879:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not part of the idle inhibition specification: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/idle-inhibit-spec/latest/
Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Attempting to use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph that has dynamic-sized tensors (tensor#-1 is a dynamic-sized tensor).
[53354:53381:1230/084357.687585:ERROR:registration_request.cc(291)] Registration response error message: DEPRECATED_ENDPOINT
[53399:53399:1230/084359.810419:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
[53399:53399:1230/084417.932408:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 2 times!
[53354:53381:1230/084427.489031:ERROR:registration_request.cc(291)] Registration response error message: DEPRECATED_ENDPOINT


$ google-chrome-stable
MESA-INTEL: warning: cannot initialize blitter engine
[53732:53732:1230/084502.130639:ERROR:content_settings_pref.cc(381)] Invalid pattern strings: http://[*.]xn--%20its%20a%20reflection%20of%20the%20commitment%20and%20heart%20that%20everyone%20brings%20to%20the%20arava%20institute,%20no%20matter%20how%20challenging%20it%20becomes-ut63i.%20,*
[53732:53732:1230/084502.309407:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not part of the idle inhibition specification: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/idle-inhibit-spec/latest/
Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Attempting to use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph that has dynamic-sized tensors (tensor#-1 is a dynamic-sized tensor).
[53732:53757:1230/084504.421696:ERROR:registration_request.cc(291)] Registration response error message: DEPRECATED_ENDPOINT
[53777:53777:1230/084506.522836:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
[53732:53757:1230/084533.659167:ERROR:registration_request.cc(291)] Registration response error message: DEPRECATED_ENDPOINT


Please open Chrome via a terminal and check for error messages showing up there. Please add those to your question.
Please also edit your question and add information how Chrome is installed.

That brings up a question. In this new age of packaged apps, how do I even know what command line is issued when I click the icon?  I suppose I can type which google-chrome or which google-chrome-stable but it is less clear than it should be.

@noisefloor: Have updated original question with the info you requested.
